# Is unsecure to have a common or easy username for a SSH server?

Tags: linux, ssh, shell

I'm aware that there are much more important things to a secure SSH server, as allowing only key based authentication, changing the port or using port knocking, implementing fail2ban, etc.

But, what are the facts, if any, to ensure that the username doesn't matter at all concerning the security of an SSH server?

Or is there any argument (for example, based on stats from brute force attempts that include username count) that supports that having an easy or guessable username would make it easy for someone trying to access our server?

I haven't found any source of information specific about the username being a threat to a secure SSH server, so it might be that it isn't, but I would like to have some confirmation on the logic of why it might be or why it isn't based on facts, references, or specific expertise.

Comment: You will likely get a lot of opinions on this.  I would revise the question to ask for stats on brute force attempts that include username counts.  There may be some honeypot sites that aggregate this data already.

Comment: Much more important is a secure account, e.g. don't use passwords, only keys, use something like fail2ban etc.

Comment: @Aaron Thanks for the feedback, I have updated my question.

Comment: In addition to keys, set restrictions on where those keys are valid from and and limit network access.

Comment: I think it is a typical compensative act. If you need to do such solutions, it is long bad. But it is only my subjective opinion, your question may be ontopic on http://security.stackexchange.com .

Comment: I will leave this closed since even after the edit you will get opinions. There are lies, dammed lies and statistics.

Comment: @Nils I updated my question again, I haven't found any info about the username being a threat to a secure SSH server, it might just be because it isn't, but I would like to have some confirmation based on stats or some valid info about that.

Comment: It's definitely not a threat. You can get a server to spit out a list of usernames from a multitude of services, and it's generally not kept as private information. Don't worry about usernames, and instead worry about locking down the accounts themselves.

Answer (score 2):

From the security perspective - I think there's no big difference between them. But as @Aaron said in the comments above, it can depend on that brute force attempts statistic.

From just my point of view - why not to make it a bit longer? At least if someone doesn't know server username, It will be harder for him to brute force it.